# Google Sheets IMPORTXML with INDEX

Tags: google-sheets, indexof

I just encountered an odd behavior with IMPORTXML in Google Sheets. When I user the function IMPORTXML, everything seems to work as intended:

[image]

But if I want only one field of the array returned from IMPORTXML using INDEX the very first cell seems to be miscalculated:

[image]

So it seems like it mistakes 4/10 with 43377. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It converts 4/10 into a date.

Please try:

`=TO_TEXT(your_formula)`

Comment: Thanks, `=INDEX(TO_TEXT(IMPORTXML(A1;"//span[@class='typo-top']"));0)` did it!